# How to produce platform-specific and platform-independent RPM subpackages from one .spec?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I have `dunno.spec` file with the following structure:

```
Name:                   dunno
Version:                 1.0
...
BuildArch:              x86_64

%description
...
%package common
Summary:                Shared files
BuildArch:              noarch
```

I suppose that after I run `rpmbuild -ba dunno.spec` I should get two binary packages:

- `dunno-1.0.x86_64.rpm`
- `dunno-common-1.0.noarch.rpm`

however I get:

- `dunno-1.0.x86_64.rpm`
- `dunno-common-1.0.x86_64.rpm`

If I remove the line `BuildArch: x86_64` from the spec, then I get

- `dunno-1.0.noarch.rpm`
- `dunno-common-1.0.noarch.rpm`

How to fix that?

RPM v4.4.2.3.

Comment: Good question. If that didn't work I'm not sure you can do it. Though it looks like it is possible in newer versions of RPM than what CentOS 5 has.

Comment: @EtanReisner: Could you please share the link to e.g. "what's new" which describes in what RPM version that feature has been implemented?

Comment: I don't know. I mentioned that only because the CentOS 6 glib2.spec has a `noarch` `-doc` package in it. [This](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/glib2.git/tree/glib2.spec?h=f18) seems to be the first tagged version of the Fedora specfile that has that. So somewhere between the CentOS 5 4.4.2.3 and whatever F18 has. Which looks like [4.10.3.1](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpm.git/tree/rpm.spec?h=f18). But that's a huge range and it might have been anywhere in there.

Comment: Yes, indeed `glib2` package has several flavours in [repo](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/21/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/g/). Hopefully this feature was not introduced by a patch (there are more then 10, but all seem to be unrelated). It seems that the only solution for v4.4 is to run `rmpbuild` twice.

Answer (score 7):

Split the build into 2 packages, one x86_64, the other noarch.

You can do 2 builds from a single spec using %ifarch logic (but
its usually easier/cleaner to use 2 spec files even if annoying).

It also hurts nothing to include platform-independent content in
an x86_64 sub-package instead of a noarch sub-package.

Comment: In case of splitting I would need to maintain other common fields like `Version`, `Url`, `License`. Also the difficulty is that common staff is installed during the build cycle, so two specs will cause two full build cycles (not good). I can of course trick the build so that "light" build cycle is run, but would be conceptually right? Inclusion does not hurt, but I have hidden part of the story: spec produces 3 platform-dependent binary packages, all of them depending on shared platform-independent staff (e.g. settings).

Comment: And how `%ifarch` can help? For example, if I add `%ifarch noarch` then again I would need to run `rpmbuild` twice (`rpmbuild --target=x86_64` and `rpmbuild --target=noarch`).

Comment: I'd just use all x86_64 sub-packages instead of attempting a noarch sub-package. Lots of x86_64 packages have only noarch content.

Comment: Yes %ifarch would need to be built twice, once for x86_64, once for noarch. But Version: etc would be identical and simple to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I think it would be reasonable for me to give up and have `.x86_64` for all packages.

Answer (score 4):

You could run the `rpmbuild` as this `rpmbuild --target=x86_64,noarch ...` then `rpmbuild` will build the package two pass for each arch.

Answer (score 0):

you should make `dunno-common` a subpackage

your spec should look like this

```
Name:                   dunno
Version:                 1.0
# next line is not needed
BuildArch:              x86_64

%package common
BuildArch:              noarch
Summary: ...
%description common
%files 
# ...

%files common
# ...
```